# grails rest client converting string to java.util.Date

Tags: json, rest, date, grails, format

I'm trying to use a rest-service created in grails 2.5.5 which has a Date property as follows:

```
import grails.rest.*

@Resource(uri='/restDomain', readOnly=true)
class RestDomain {
    Date myDate
}
```

But when calling from another grails app (v2.5.5 or v3.1.9) like this:

```
new RestBuilder().get('http://localhost:8080/restApp/restDomain.json').json.collect {
    new RestDomain(it)
}
```

I get a `Cannot cast object '2016-01-20T12:36:57Z' with class 'java.lang.String' to class 'java.util.Date'` error.

I've already added this in application.yml (grails v3.1.9) at the very bottom of the file

```
---
grails:
    databinding:
        dateFormats:
            - yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX
            - yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX
```

and this in Config.groovy (grails v2.5.5)

```
grails.databinding.dateFormats = ["yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX"]
```

but doesn't seem to work at all

Note: In both client apps I have the corresponding `src/groovy/restApp/RestDomain.groovy` class as follows:

```
package restApp

class RestDomain {
    Date myDate
}
```

Note 2: The grails 3.1.9 client app has `compile 'org.grails:grails-datastore-rest-client:6.0.0.M1'` dependency the in build.gradle dependencies section, and the grails 2.5.5 client app has `compile ':rest-client-builder:2.1.1'` in the BuildConfig.groovy plugins section

Any help getting it to work in a Grails 2.5.x or Grails 3.1.x app would be really appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The 'Z' at the end of your date string signifies that the time zone is UTC which is not a valid [ISO 8601 time zone specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#iso8601timezone) that you could parse with the 'X' in your time formats. It is a literal that should be parseable with

```
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'
```

Comment: I had already tried with that format, the problem seems to be that databinding isn't working at all, I will try with some other simple formats to verify if it is the 'T' or the 'Z'

Comment: I added the BindUsing annotation on the class like this: `@BindUsing({ obj, source -> source.getPropertyValue('myDate' as Date) })` and it doesn't work either, in fact, I guess that the conversion `as Date` breaks the program

Answer (score 0):

Adding an answer to provide a workaround on how I resolved this, but I will not mark it as the accepted answer because it is not the ideal way to solved it, so here it is:

Added this in my client controller (I guess that the `bindData` method is the key here):

```
new RestBuilder().get('http://localhost:8080/restApp/restDomain.json').json.collect {
    def restDomainInstance = new RestDomain()
    bindData(restDomainInstance, it)
    restDomainInstance
}
```

and changed `RestDomain.groovy` to this

```
package restApp

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import org.grails.databinding.BindUsing

class RestDomain {
    @BindUsing({ obj, source ->
        new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX")
            .parse(source.getPropertyValue('myDate'))
    })
    Date myDate
}
```

The `X` in the SimpleDateFormat is for recognizing the timezone as UTC, so the jvm converts it to its current timezone later (in my case: -04:00 GMT)